# Maximum call stack size exceeded problema con ajax js

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

Estoy validando la modificación de contraseña.
en una función ejecuto a `sw = await checkCurrentPassword()`

```
const checkCurrentPassword =  () => {
var res =  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/checkCurrentPassword',
    data: { currentPassword: $('#currentPassword') }
})
return res
```

}

```
public function checkCurrentPassword(Request $request)
{
    $salt = '$5$rounds=5000$' . Auth::user()->email . "$";
    $hash = crypt($request->currentPassword, $salt);

    $user = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->where('password',$hash)->first();
    if(isset($user)){
        return response()->json(true);
    }else{
        return response()->json(false);
    }
}
```

cuando ejecuto la función me tira un error de Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: No estoy seguro si es la solución, pero intenta cambiando el nombre de la constante para que sea diferente al nombre de la función.

Comment: Saca el `await ` porque tu función no es asíncrona